# Can I use 'index' in PageView widget in other widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, pageviews

I'm making an app divided to two sections: one(upper section) is `PageView` widget area, another(lower section) is `Container` widget area. I want the lower section to show 'we are in X page' when I change pages in the upper section.

I tried to use `index` of PageView widget in Container widget, but console said "undefined name 'index'".
So I declared like `int index;` as a global variable, and tried again, but it doesn't work. I think this `index` is different from `index` of PageView widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  var scrollDirection = Axis.horizontal;
  var actionIcon = Icons.swap_vert;
  int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('it\'s a drill for page view'),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: PageView.builder(
              controller: controller,
              itemCount: 5,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text('it is ${index} page');
              },
            )
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text('we are in ${index} page!'),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm a beginner of programming, and doing this as a hobby.
But I really like it. Actually I gave up my own study and career and stick to programming now. I hope you help me solve this problem.
Thank you. I love you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes. like `controller.page` for the current page.

```
class Sample extends StatelessWidget{

final int value;
Sample(this.value);

build(context) => Text("you are in $value");
}
```

and use `Sample(controller.page)`

EDIT: your code should be

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  var scrollDirection = Axis.horizontal;
  var actionIcon = Icons.swap_vert;
  int currentPage=0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('it\'s a drill for page view'),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: PageView.builder(
                controller: controller,
                itemCount: 5,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Text('it is ${index} page');
                },
                onPageChanged: (page){
                  setState(() {
                    currentPage=page;
                  });
                },
              )
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text('we are in ${currentPage} page!'),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Thanks to your help, I got the result almost I wanted.

Comment: But there are still two problems. One is Sample(controller.page) seems double. Although I declared value as int, the console says "The argument type 'double' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'." So I declared value as double, it worked. 
Unfortunately another problem comes here. When I run the emulator, it seems to work well, but it doesn't change the number(ie. 3.0 because I declared it as double) at all, when I change pages. 
I think that's because I made Sample class as statelessWidget, but not sure

Comment: use `controller.page.toInt()`

Comment: for the second part you need to call `setState()`  in your class that holds the pageview for refreshing the ui. There is function onPageChanged(int) see(https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) which is called on page change so call setState in here

Comment: I'm really sorry to make you wait. I have a lot of things to do as a student. I think I can't check your solution today. Could you give me some time?

Comment: I wrote the code without editor so I thought if I was my code that didn't work that's all

Comment: It doesn't work..but thank you for your sincere help. I'm using android studio.

Comment: I finally solved this problem thanks to you! It really works perfect now. Thank you very much. I hope your day be happy! With Love.

Answer (score 4):

Just add listener to PageController like that:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    index = 0;
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        index = controller.page.toInt();
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for replying me. Can I ask you where PageController is? I'm terribly sorry that I'm a beginner in this programming. I think I can't check right now. Finishing something to do, I'll check.

Comment: here he is `final controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);`

Comment: it works perfect! Thank you very much. But it makes some time difference. the lower one follows the upper one with about 0.5 second. Any suggestion?

Comment: Replace `controller.page.toInt()` with `controller.page.round()`, and delay will disappear.

Comment: There is still some delay. I'll make a new question about that. If you're free, please come to help me to the new question.